# How to associate 3 models together in cakephp 3.6

Tags: mysql, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I have 3 tables

**orders Tables**

```
id,name
21 Test
22 NewTest
```

**driverdetails tables**

```
id,order_id,user_id
1   21        5
2   21        6
```

**Users Tables**

```
id,name
5  Raj
6  Sonu
```

I want to join orders tables with driverdetails tables base on order_id and driver table with users table based on user_id.So that i was able to get all user name where order_id = 21

I am running a select query on orders tables

My orders belongs to driver details and driver belongs to users,i need all name from users tables based on order id and user_id

Expected result on association in orders tables

```
5 Raj
6 Sonu
```

**below is my code which i tried**

```
$this->belongsTo('DriverDetails', [
                'className' => 'DriverDetails',
                'foreignKey' => 'order_id'
            ]);
            $this->belongsTo('DriverDetails', [
                'className' => 'Users',
                'foreignKey' => 'user_id'
            ]);
```

Comment: Seems you are making a little confusion. Following your schema seems that `Orders` don't belongsTo `DriverDetails` but rather they hasMany `DriverDetails`. Also if you'd like to follow the conventions the table name in mysql should be `drivers_details`

Comment: @arilia Shouldn't that be `driver_details` instead of `drivers_details`

Comment: @PradeepSingh yes, it was a typo

Comment: Yes in mysql it is driver_details but in cakephp model association we will write it as DriverDetails..and yes order has many drivers associated with order_id

Comment: so, why did you try `belongsTo` when you have `hasMany` relationship?

Comment: plz help me if you know how to associate this relationship to get expected result.